# No gray cue banner or text prompts on webpage

Tags: javascript, vb6

I am running the 64 bit version of Windows 8 with Internet Explorer 11.

I have Java installed and updated.

I am using the Internet Explorer webbrowser control in my webbrowser application.

When I use my program and I go to  http://www.gotapparel.com/signin.aspx, I am not able to view the gray cue banner or text prompts.

When I use Internet Explorer I am able to see the gray cue banner or text prompts:

```
Your Email Address

Your Password

First Name

Last Name

Enter email address

Password

Re-Type Password
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is a rendering issue because the Webbrowser control by default renders as IE 7. There is a registry hack where you add your application as a DWORD key to the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION key and specify the IE rendering mode version to use. You can add it for the current user, or all users.

For instance: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\MyApp.exe`, with a value of 11001 (0x2EDF) is for IE11 standards mode regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive in the html page.

The full explanation with examples and rendering values is fairly lengthy so I've just included a link.

[Web Browser Control – Specifying the IE Version](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version)